# Kotlin Coroutines : Waiting for multiple threads to finish

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, parallel-processing, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

So looking at Coroutines for the first time, I want to process a load of data in parallel and wait for it to finish.  I been looking around and seen RunBlocking and Await etc but not sure how to use it.

I so far have

```
val jobs = mutableListOf<Job>()
jobs += GlobalScope.launch { processPages(urls, collection) }
jobs += GlobalScope.launch { processPages(urls, collection2) }
jobs += GlobalScope.launch { processPages(urls, collection3) }
```

I then want to know/wait for these to finish

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You don't need to manually keep track of your cuncurrent jobs if you use the concept of structured concurrency. Assuming that your `processPages` function performs some kind of blocking IO, you can encapsulate your code into the following suspending function, which executes your code in an IO dispatcher designed for this kind of work:

```
suspend fun processAllPages() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { 
    // withContext waits for all children coroutines 
    launch { processPages(urls, collection) }
    launch { processPages(urls, collection2) }
    launch { processPages(urls, collection3) }
}
```

Now, from if a topmost function of your application is not already a suspending function, then you can use `runBlocking` to call `processAllPages`:

```
runBlocking {
    processAllPages()
}
```

Comment: Would this run all of the jobs in parallel?

Comment: I am getting suppend function processAllPages() should only be called from another coroutine or suppsend function

Comment: @Burf2000 call processAllPages() inside runBlocking method.

Answer (score 15):

You can use `async` builder function to process a load of data in parallel:

```
class Presenter {
    private var job: Job = Job()
    private var scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job) // creating the scope to run the coroutine. It consists of Dispatchers.Main (coroutine will run in the Main context) and job to handle the cancellation of the coroutine.

    fun runInParallel() {
        scope.launch { // launch a coroutine
            // runs in parallel
            val deferredList = listOf(
                    scope.asyncIO { processPages(urls, collection) },
                    scope.asyncIO { processPages(urls, collection2) },
                    scope.asyncIO { processPages(urls, collection3) }
            )

            deferredList.awaitAll() // wait for all data to be processed without blocking the UI thread

            // do some stuff after data has been processed, for example update UI
        }
    }

    private fun processPages(...) {...}

    fun cancel() {
        job.cancel() // invoke it to cancel the job when you don't need it to execute. For example when UI changed and you don't need to process data
    }
}
```

Extension function `asyncIO`:

```
fun <T> CoroutineScope.asyncIO(ioFun: () -> T) = async(Dispatchers.IO) { ioFun() } // CoroutineDispatcher - runs and schedules coroutines
```

`GlobalScope.launch` [is not recommended to use](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/) unless you want the coroutine to be operating on the whole application lifetime and not cancelled prematurely.

Edit: as mentioned by Roman Elizarov you can try not to use `awaitAll()` function unless you want to update UI or do something else right away after all data are processed.

Comment: There is no need for `async` since result is not used here. There is also no need to do  `awaitAll`, since an outer coroutine waits for all the children anyway.

Comment: I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/coroutines/jvm/internal/CoroutineImpl
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)

Comment: @Burf2000 I guess it is because of using `Dispatchers.Main`. Please check the Guide to replace it with appropriate Dispatcher https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md.

Comment: I changed it to default, made sure I had the latest Coroutine frameworks and everything runs lovely

Comment: Actually this is not working, var processor =  Processor()
    processor.runInParallel()
    println("finished") is printed instantly

Comment: What is the `Processor`, where do you print "finished"? If you print it right after `processor.runInParallel()` then of course it will be printed instantly because coroutine is launched without blocking the current thread (where processor.runInParallel() is invoked).

Answer (score 5):

Following approach can be used.

```
fun myTask() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        val task = listOf(
            async {

            },
            async {

            }
        )
        task.awaitAll()

    }
}
```