# Chained & concurrent coroutines with Retrofit

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

I have a method `fetchItineraries` in a manager class which should fetch a list of itineraries based on an input list (ids) of departure points. For every `Station`, the availability needs to be checked using an HTTP POST call that returns an id which should be used immediately on the next HTTP GET call to find the itinerary.

```
fun fetchItineraries(departure: Station) {
    val stations = departure.getDepartureStations()

    //Fetch all availabilities
    scope.launch {
        stations.forEach {
            println("Station: ${it.name}")
            getAvailability(station)
        }
    }
}
```

As far as I understand, a coroutine is launched on the Main thread (using `Dispatchers.Main`). Retrofit handles the async/await internally and dispatches the request under the hood (using the `enqueue` method).

```
suspend fun getAvailability(station: Station) {
    try {
        val response = Api.networkApi.getAvailability(station.id)

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            val requestId = response.body()?.requestId ?: ""

            //Fetch the itinerary
            fetchItinerary(requestId)
        }
    } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {

    }
}
```

Now the main thread is displaying a non-blocking loading indicator and once all calls have been made (all possible itineraries have been fetched), the results should be displayed and the indicator is removed.

In my current application, I receive the following log lines:

> Fetching availability for station: 1
>   Availabilities found for station: 1
>   Fetching itineraries for station: 1
>   Itineraries fetched for station: 1
>
> ---
>
> Fetching availability for station: 2
>   Availabilities found for station: 2
>   Fetching itineraries for station: 2
>   Itineraries fetched for station: 2

However, I want to result to be the following (a possible outcome):

> Fetching availability for station: 1
>   Fetching availability for station: 2
>   Availabilities found for station: 1
>   Fetching itineraries for station: 1
>   Availabilities found for station: 2
>   Fetching itineraries for station: 2
>   Itineraries fetched for station: 2
>   Itineraries fetched for station: 1

Comment: Hi! This seems more suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Enselic It could be, if there's more context. I'd strongly recommend OP to read [their FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2437/52915) before posting it there, since I'm not sure it would survive if migrated as-is.

Comment: @Mast I've added some additional context information about my problem. I don't think it's suitable for codereview since I'm looking to solve this issue using coroutines. I should have explained my problem more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can just launch a child coroutine for every station:

```
//Fetch all availabilities
scope.launch {
    stations.forEach {
        println("Station: ${it.name}")
        launch { getAvailability(it) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer in combination with https://stackoverflow.com/a/54856079/798314 solved my issue.