# How to force rest calls in parallel using Kotlin coroutines?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin-coroutines

I have looked around and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854187/kotlin-coroutines-waiting-for-multiple-threads-to-finish) explaining how to execute code in parallel, however my code is running in a Spring Boot app, not on Android, so I believe the dispatchers should be different.

At any rate, the following code does not run in parallel (only runs on a single thread -- http-nio-8080-exec-1 -- in sequence). So, it's taking over 4 seconds when it should take a little more than 2 seconds:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate

@RestController
class CoroutineController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    suspend fun find(): String {
        var result = ""
        coroutineScope {
            val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
            println(Thread.currentThread().name + "   starting at " + start)
            val product = async {
                findById()
            }
            val product2 = async {
                findById2()
            }
             result = product.await() + product2.await()
            println(Thread.currentThread().name + "   ending  " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start))
        }
        return result
    }

    suspend fun findById(): String {
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + "   starting find 1")
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
        val response = restTemplate.getForObject("https://httpbin.org/ip", String::class.java)
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        return response!!
    }

    suspend fun findById2(): String {
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + "   starting find 2")
        val restTemplate = RestTemplate()
        val response = restTemplate.getForObject("https://httpbin.org/ip", String::class.java)
        Thread.sleep(2000)
        return response!!
    }

}
```

Output in console:

```
http-nio-8080-exec-1   starting at 1607845427335
http-nio-8080-exec-1   starting find 1
http-nio-8080-exec-1   starting find 2
http-nio-8080-exec-1   ending  4783
```

How to best make the calls `findById` and `findById2` to run in parallel (i.e. on separate threads) so as to save loading time?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like simply appending `(Dispatchers.Default)` to one of the `async`s forces parallelism. However I'm open to other answers or critiques, as to how best to offload IO tasks to a background thread in a non-Android Kotlin app.

Example working code:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.coroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val res = find()
        println("result is $res")
    }
}

suspend fun find(): String {
    var result = ""
    coroutineScope {
        val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + "   starting at " + start)
        val product = async(Dispatchers.Default) {
            findById()
        }
        val product2 = async {
            findById2()
        }
        result = product.await() + product2.await()
        println(Thread.currentThread().name + "   ending  " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start))
    }
    return result
}
fun findById(): String {
    println(Thread.currentThread().name + "   starting find 1")
    val response = "a"
    Thread.sleep(2000) //make IO call here
    return response
}

fun findById2(): String {
    println(Thread.currentThread().name + "   starting find 2")
    val response = "b"
    Thread.sleep(2000) //make IO call here
    return response
}
```

Result:

```
main   starting at 1608844986270
DefaultDispatcher-worker-1   starting find 1
main   starting find 2
main   ending  2042
result is ab
```

Ref: https://kotlinexpertise.com/kotlin-coroutines-concurrency

Answer (score 1):

Might be a little late to answer this question but according to Kotlin docs `Dispatcher.Unconfined` results most commonly in execution in the same thread as it was invoked from. So mostly it will be main, or in this example a http-nio thread which is a request thread. Overall `Dispatcher.Unconfined` should be avoided.

In most cases `Dispatcher.IO` should be used, and in your example the easiest and cleanest solution would be to assign a `withContex(Dispatcher.IO)` to your function like so:

```
@GetMapping("/")
suspend fun find(): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
    val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println(Thread.currentThread().name + "   starting at " + start)
    val product = async {
        findById()
    }
    val product2 = async {
        findById2()
    }
    println(Thread.currentThread().name + "   ending  " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start))
    product.await() + product2.await()
}
```